# correct way of calling an API for ionic 3 in the device

Tags: mobile, ionic3

currently my post is not working and giving me an error "this.http.post(...).map is not a function"

i was wonderin if you can help me here to modify this code for an Ionic application is this the right way to do it?

myImage;

recognize(){
    let headers = new Headers();

```
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('apikey', 'myApI');
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.myImage, this.myImage.name);
this.http.post('https://api.taggun.io/api/receipt/v1/simple/file', formData, {headers: headers})
  .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =>{
    console.log(data);
    this.data = data;
    this.navCtrl.push(ScanResultsPage, {data: data})
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

let postData = {
        "name": "Krunal",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "tel": "12345678"
}

this.http.post("URL WILL HERE", postData, requestOptions)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data['_body']);
   }, error => {
   console.log(error);
});
```